# PHPMailer with codeigniter is not sending mails

Tags: php, linux, codeigniter, sendmail, phpmailer

I created a website on a windows server using codeigniter and phpmailer for its contact form, this setup works well. After a few days ago I decided to make another website on a Linux server, I used almost the same codes but my contact form doesn't seem to work.

Code in my controller

```
$email_config=array(
                    "protocol"=>"smtp",
                    "mailpath"=>"/usr/sbin/sendmail",
                    "smtp_host"=>"mail.dnweb-solutions.com",
                    "smtp_user"=>"contact@mail.dnweb-solutions.com",
                    "smtp_pass"=>"****",
                    "smtp_port"=>25,
                );
                $this->load->library("email");
                $this->email->initialize($email_config);
                $this->email->to("sobsdinike@gmail.com");
                $this->email->from("contact@mail.dnweb-solutions.com",$_POST["fullname"]);
                $this->email->reply_to($_POST["email"],$_POST["fullname"]);
                $this->email->subject($_POST["subject"]);
                $this->email->message($_POST["message"]);
                $this->email->send();
```

Code in my config/email.php

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');

$config['useragent']        = 'PHPMailer';              // Mail engine     switcher: 'CodeIgniter' or 'PHPMailer'
$config['protocol']         = 'smtp';                   // 'mail', 'sendmail', or 'smtp'
$config['mailpath']         = '/usr/sbin/sendmail';
$config['smtp_host']        = 'mail.dnweb-solutions.com';
$config['smtp_user']        = 'contact@mail.dnweb-solutions.com';
$config['smtp_pass']        = '****';
$config['smtp_port']        = 25;
$config['smtp_timeout']     = 5;                        // (in seconds)
$config['smtp_crypto']      = '';                       // '' or 'tls' or 'ssl'
$config['smtp_debug']       = 0;                        // PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level: 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
$config['wordwrap']         = true;
$config['wrapchars']        = 76;
$config['mailtype']         = 'html';                   // 'text' or 'html'
$config['charset']          = 'utf-8';
$config['validate']         = true;
$config['priority']         = 3;                        // 1, 2, 3, 4, 5
$config['crlf']             = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['newline']          = "\n";                     // "\r\n" or "\n" or "\r"
$config['bcc_batch_mode']   = false;
$config['bcc_batch_size']   = 200;
$config['encoding']         = '8bit';                   // The body encoding. For CodeIgniter: '8bit' or '7bit'. For PHPMailer: '8bit', '7bit', 'binary', 'base64', or 'quoted-printable'.
```

Code on MY_Email.php (this is incomplete but this is the one available on github)

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed.');
class MY_Email extends CI_Email {

public $phpmailer;  // This property has been made public for testing purposes.

protected $mailer_engine = 'codeigniter';
protected $CI;

protected $_is_ci_3 = NULL;

protected static $protocols = array('mail', 'sendmail', 'smtp');
protected static $mailtypes = array('html', 'text');
protected static $encodings_ci = array('8bit', '7bit');
protected static $encodings_phpmailer = array('8bit', '7bit', 'binary', 'base64', 'quoted-printable');

public function __construct($config = array()) {

    $this->_is_ci_3 = (bool) ((int) CI_VERSION >= 3);

    $this->CI = get_instance();
    $this->CI->load->helper('email');
    $this->CI->load->helper('html');

    if (!is_array($config)) {
        $config = array();
    }

    if (isset($config['useragent'])) {

        $useragent = trim($config['useragent']);
        $mailer_engine = strtolower($useragent);

        if (strpos($mailer_engine, 'phpmailer') !== false) {
            $this->mailer_engine = 'phpmailer';
        } elseif(strpos($mailer_engine, 'codeigniter') !== false) {
            $this->mailer_engine = 'codeigniter';
        } else {
            unset($config['useragent']);    // An invalid setting;
        }
    }

    if (isset($config['charset'])) {

        $charset = trim($config['charset']);

        if ($charset != '') {
            $this->charset = $charset;
            unset($config['charset']);      // We don't need this anymore.
        }

    } else {

        $charset = trim(config_item('charset'));

        if ($charset != '') {
            $this->charset = $charset;
        }
    }

    $this->charset = strtoupper($this->charset);

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        // If your system uses class autoloading feature,
        // then the following require statement would not be needed.
        if (!class_exists('PHPMailer', false)) {
            require_once APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
        }
        //

        $this->phpmailer = new PHPMailer();
        $this->phpmailer->PluginDir = APPPATH.'third_party/phpmailer/';

        $this->_copy_property_to_phpmailer('charset');
    }

    if (count($config) > 0) {

        $this->initialize($config);

    } else {

        $this->_smtp_auth = ($this->smtp_user == '' AND $this->smtp_pass == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;

        if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
            $this->_copy_property_to_phpmailer('_smtp_auth');
        }
    }

    $this->_safe_mode = ( ! is_php('5.4') && ini_get('safe_mode'));

    log_message('info', 'MY_Email Class Initialized (Engine: '.$this->mailer_engine.')');
}

/**
 * Define these options within the $config array or
 * within the configuration file email.php:
 * useragent
 * protocol
 * mailpath
 * smtp_host
 * smtp_user
 * smtp_pass
 * smtp_port
 * smtp_timeout
 * smtp_crypto
 * set_wordwrap
 * wrapchars
 * mailtype
 * charset
 * validate
 * priority
 * crlf
 * newline
 * bcc_batch_mode
 * bcc_batch_size
 * encoding
 */
public function initialize($config = array()) {

    if (!is_array($config)) {
        $config = array();
    }

    foreach ($config as $key => $val) {

        $method = 'set_'.$key;

        if (method_exists($this, $method)) {

            $this->$method($val);

        } elseif (isset($this->$key)) {

            $this->$key = $val;

            if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
                $this->_copy_property_to_phpmailer($key);
            }
        }
    }

    $this->clear();

    $this->_smtp_auth = ($this->smtp_user == '' AND $this->smtp_pass == '') ? FALSE : TRUE;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
        $this->_copy_property_to_phpmailer('_smtp_auth');
    }

    return $this;
}

public function clear($clear_attachments = false) {

    $clear_attachments = !empty($clear_attachments);

    parent::clear($clear_attachments);

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $this->phpmailer->clearAllRecipients();
        $this->phpmailer->clearReplyTos();
        if ($clear_attachments) {
            $this->phpmailer->clearAttachments();
        }

        $this->phpmailer->clearCustomHeaders();

        $this->phpmailer->Subject = '';
        $this->phpmailer->Body = '';
        $this->phpmailer->AltBody = '';
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set_protocol($protocol = 'mail') {

    $protocol = trim(strtolower($protocol));

    $this->protocol = in_array($protocol, self::$protocols) ? $protocol : 'mail';

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        switch ($this->protocol) {

            case 'mail':
                $this->phpmailer->isMail();
                break;

            case 'sendmail':
                $this->phpmailer->isSendmail();
                break;

            case 'smtp':
                $this->phpmailer->isSMTP();
                break;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set_smtp_crypto($smtp_crypto = '') {

    $smtp_crypto = trim(strtolower($smtp_crypto));

    if ($smtp_crypto != 'tls' && $smtp_crypto != 'ssl') {
        $smtp_crypto = '';
    }

    $this->smtp_crypto = $smtp_crypto;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
        $this->phpmailer->SMTPSecure = $smtp_crypto;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set_wordwrap($wordwrap = TRUE) {

    $this->wordwrap = !empty($wordwrap);

    if (!$this->wordwrap) {

        if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
            $this->phpmailer->WordWrap = 0;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set_mailtype($type = 'text') {

    $type = trim(strtolower($type));

    $this->mailtype = in_array($type, self::$mailtypes) ? $type : 'text';

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
        $this->phpmailer->isHTML($this->mailtype == 'html');
    }

    return $this;
}

public function set_priority($n = 3) {

    $this->priority = preg_match('/^[1-5]$/', $n) ? (int) $n : 3;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
        $this->phpmailer->Priority = $this->priority;
    }

    return $this;
}

public function valid_email($email) {

    return valid_email($email);
}

public function from($from, $name = '', $return_path = NULL) {

    $from = (string) $from;
    $name = (string) $name;
    $return_path = (string) $return_path;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        if (preg_match( '/\<(.*)\>/', $from, $match)) {
            $from = $match['1'];
        }

        if ($this->validate) {

            $this->validate_email($this->_str_to_array($from));

            if ($return_path) {
                $this->validate_email($this->_str_to_array($return_path));
            }
        }

        $this->phpmailer->setFrom($from, $name, 0);

        if (!$return_path) {
            $return_path = $from;
        }

        $this->phpmailer->Sender = $return_path;

    } else {

        if ($this->_is_ci_3) {
            parent::from($from, $name, $return_path);
        } else {
            parent::from($from, $name);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function reply_to($replyto, $name = '') {

    $replyto = (string) $replyto;
    $name = (string) $name;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        if (preg_match( '/\<(.*)\>/', $replyto, $match)) {
            $replyto = $match['1'];
        }

        if ($this->validate) {
            $this->validate_email($this->_str_to_array($replyto));
        }

        if ($name == '') {
            $name = $replyto;
        }

        $this->phpmailer->addReplyTo($replyto, $name);

        $this->_replyto_flag = TRUE;

    } else {

        parent::reply_to($replyto, $name);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function to($to) {

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $to = $this->_str_to_array($to);
        $names = $this->_extract_name($to);
        $to = $this->clean_email($to);

        if ($this->validate) {
            $this->validate_email($to);
        }

        reset($names);

        foreach ($to as $address) {

            list($key, $name) = each($names);
            $this->phpmailer->addAddress($address, $name);
        }

    } else {

        parent::to($to);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function cc($cc) {

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $cc = $this->_str_to_array($cc);
        $names = $this->_extract_name($cc);
        $cc = $this->clean_email($cc);

        if ($this->validate) {
            $this->validate_email($cc);
        }

        reset($names);

        foreach ($cc as $address) {

            list($key, $name) = each($names);
            $this->phpmailer->addCC($address, $name);
        }

    } else {

        parent::cc($cc);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function bcc($bcc, $limit = '') {

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $bcc = $this->_str_to_array($bcc);
        $names = $this->_extract_name($bcc);
        $bcc = $this->clean_email($bcc);

        if ($this->validate) {
            $this->validate_email($bcc);
        }

        reset($names);

        foreach ($bcc as $address) {

            list($key, $name) = each($names);
            $this->phpmailer->addBCC($address, $name);
        }

    } else {

        parent::bcc($bcc, $limit);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function subject($subject) {

    $subject = (string) $subject;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

       $this->phpmailer->Subject = (string) $subject;

    } else {

        parent::subject($subject);
    }

    return $this;
}

public function message($body) {

    $body = (string) $body;

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $this->phpmailer->Body = $body;
    }

    parent::message($body);

    return $this;
}

// Modified by Ivan Tcholakov, 16-JAN-2014.
//public function attach($file, $disposition = '', $newname = NULL, $mime = '') {
public function attach($file, $disposition = '', $newname = NULL, $mime = '', $embedded_image = false) {
//

    $file = (string) $file;

    $disposition = (string) $disposition;

    if ($disposition == '') {
        $disposition ='attachment';
    }

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        $newname = (string) $newname;
        $mime = (string) $mime;

        if ($mime == '') {

            if (strpos($file, '://') === FALSE && ! file_exists($file)) {

                $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_attachment_missing', $file);
                // Modified by Ivan Tcholakov, 14-JAN-2014.
                //return FALSE;
                return $this;
                //
            }

            if (!$fp = @fopen($file, FOPEN_READ)) {

                $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_attachment_unreadable', $file);
                // Modified by Ivan Tcholakov, 14-JAN-2014.
                //return FALSE;
                return $this;
                //
            }

            $file_content = stream_get_contents($fp);
            $mime = $this->_mime_types(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
            fclose($fp);

            $newname = basename($file);

        } else {

            $file_content =& $file; // Buffered file.
            // Added by Ivan Tcholakov, 14-JAN-2014.
            $file = $newname;
            //
        }

        $this->_attachments[] = array(
            'name' => array($file, $newname),
            'disposition' => $disposition,
            'type' => $mime,
        );

        if (empty($embedded_image)) {

            $this->phpmailer->addStringAttachment($file_content, $newname, 'base64', $mime, $disposition);

        } else {

            $cid = $this->attachment_cid($file);
            $this->phpmailer->addStringEmbeddedImage($file_content, $cid, $newname, 'base64', $mime, $disposition);
        }

    } else {

        if ($this->_is_ci_3) {
            parent::attach($file, $disposition, $newname, $mime);
        } else {
            parent::attach($file, $disposition);
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function attachment_cid($filename) {

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        for ($i = 0, $c = count($this->_attachments); $i < $c; $i++) {

            if ($this->_attachments[$i]['name'][0] === $filename) {

                $this->_attachments[$i]['cid'] = uniqid(basename($this->_attachments[$i]['name'][0]).'@');
                return $this->_attachments[$i]['cid'];
            }
        }

    } elseif ($this->_is_ci_3) {

        return parent::attachment_cid($filename);
    }

    return FALSE;
}

// Added by Ivan Tcholakov, 16-JAN-2014.
public function get_attachment_cid($filename) {

    for ($i = 0, $c = count($this->_attachments); $i < $c; $i++) {

        if ($this->_attachments[$i]['name'][0] === $filename) {
            return empty($this->_attachments[$i]['cid']) ? FALSE : $this->_attachments[$i]['cid'];
        }
    }

    return FALSE;
}
//

public function send($auto_clear = true) {

    $auto_clear = !empty($auto_clear);

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        if ($this->mailtype == 'html') {
            $this->phpmailer->AltBody = $this->_get_alt_message();
        }

        $result = (bool) $this->phpmailer->send();

        if ($result) {

            $this->_set_error_message('lang:email_sent', $this->_get_protocol());

            if ($auto_clear) {
                $this->clear();
            }

        } else {

            $this->_set_error_message($this->phpmailer->ErrorInfo);
        }

    } else {

        if ($this->_is_ci_3) {
            $result = parent::send($auto_clear);
        } else {
            $result = parent::send();
        }
    }

    return $result;
}


// Custom methods ----------------------------------------------------------

// Setting explicitly the body encoding.
// See https://github.com/ivantcholakov/codeigniter-phpmailer/issues/3
public function set_encoding($encoding) {

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {

        if (!in_array($encoding, self::$encodings_phpmailer)) {
            $encoding = '8bit';
        }

        $this->phpmailer->Encoding = $encoding;

    } elseif (!in_array($encoding, self::$encodings_ci)) {

        $encoding = '8bit';
    }

    $this->_encoding = $encoding;

    return $this;
}

// PHPMailer's SMTP debug info level
// 0 = off, 1 = commands, 2 = commands and data, 3 = as 2 plus connection status, 4 = low level data output.
public function set_smtp_debug($level) {

    $level = (int) $level;

    if ($level < 0) {
        $level = 0;
    }

    if ($this->mailer_engine == 'phpmailer') {
        $this->phpmailer->SMTPDebug = $level;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

Comment: if that's actually your password, please remove it immediately (and then go change it).

Comment: any error messages? have you checked the logs? Explain further why you think it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: Jordan no i did not provide the actual passwords. @Juan that's actually one of my problems, i don't see any error logs on my webserver. I also checked my smtp server logs my other website seems to work well but my linux webserver have no trace of connection on that log.

Comment: Have you tried using the print_debugger() method? Sometimes it will give useful information on what happened during the process. Try "echo $this->email->print_debugger();" after you do "$this->email->send()".

Comment: @Xylude tried that, it doesn't return anything.

Comment: This is weird, I tried to copy the files on a windows server and changed nothing but file paths on the code, and everything works perfectly.